# Azure-based approach for sending 100000 requests to external service

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-data-factory, azure-webjobs

Every night I need to get data from external http service and save it to Azure Data Lake.
Actually, I need to get all the orders for all the customers. The problem is that there is now way to get this data via a single call. Id of a customer should be provided per each separate call.

The format of url is something like /api/ordersByCutomer/{cutomerId}

I need to get data for 100 000 different customers. It will result in 100 000 calls to the external service.

I tried to use Azure Data Factory with Foreach activity in parallel mode, but it takes 4 sec per each call there (3 seconds are spent in queue). The overall speed result was not satisfying.

What is the best (I mean the fastest) azure-based approach for this (except Azure Data Factory)?

Thanks

Comment: Are you also looking at a programmatically way of doing it? You could use a Azure Webjob do run some (python) scripts that can do this and run those in parallel.

Answer (score 2):

You could write some [asynchronous code](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58349111/9766182) to hit the API/http service parallelly and execute this code using custom activity in ADF which works by using batch account to get this job done. [Use custom activities in an Azure Data Factory](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-factory/transform-data-using-custom-activity)

Also, before doing any of this it would nice to contact the owner/stakeholder of the external http service and finding out if there is rate limiting on that service and even if the service can handle such loads.